# Azure cognitive search suggestion

Tags: azure, search

We are using Azure cognitive search to search PDF documents.We are using Azure blob storage for storing PDF files. Our requirement is to retrieve only portion of the text(5 words) not the whole documents(100 pages) .
So when we search for text "money " , we would like to end up "Money bribe .. " , "money landuring ..." and not the whole  document itself

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use [built-in key phrase extraction capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-keyphrases) to extract the key from the content.